# How to properly apply a nested loop?

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I want to print pandas-column-based concatenated strings.

To accomplish this I applied three for-loops to iterate over each element:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'code': ['A180', 'A181'], 'company': ['XYZ', 'XYZ'], 'title':['vice president', 'vice president'], 'other_title':['sr vice president', 'sr vice president']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
cities = ["Buffalo", "Houston", "Boston"]


codes = df['code']
titles=df['title']

for city in cities:
    for title in titles:
        for code in codes:
             print(code+'-'+city+'-'+title)
```

Which output's print code option twice:

```
#A180-Buffalo-vice president
#A181-Buffalo-vice president
#A180-Buffalo-vice president
#A181-Buffalo-vice president
#A180-Houston-vice president
#A181-Houston-vice president
#A180-Houston-vice president
#A181-Houston-vice president
#A180-Boston-vice president
#A181-Boston-vice president
#A180-Boston-vice president
#A181-Boston-vice president
```

How to get just the concatenated string once?
Something like this:

```
#A180-Buffalo-vice president
#A181-Buffalo-vice president
#A180-Houston-vice president
#A181-Houston-vice president
#A180-Boston-vice president
#A181-Boston-vice president
```

Comment: Perhaps `codes = df['code'].unique(); titles = df['title'].unique()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `df['title']` contains `duplicates`.

Use [`Series.unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) to get only distinct values:

```
In [1446]: titles = df['title'].unique()
```

Then run your `for` loop:

```
In [1448]: for city in cities:
      ...:     for title in titles:
      ...:         for code in codes:
      ...:              print(code+'-'+city+'-'+title)
      ...: 
A180-Buffalo-vice president
A181-Buffalo-vice president
A180-Houston-vice president
A181-Houston-vice president
A180-Boston-vice president
A181-Boston-vice president
```

Answer (score 2):

But maybe you don't even need 3 loops:

```
from itertools import product

print('\n'.join([
    x[1][0]+'-'+x[0]+'-'+x[1][1]
    for x in product(cities, zip(d['code'], d['title']))]))
```

Output:

```
A180-Buffalo-vice president
A181-Buffalo-vice president
A180-Houston-vice president
A181-Houston-vice president
A180-Boston-vice president
A181-Boston-vice president
```